# Как работает метод len() в Python?

Tags: python

Метод `len()` вернет длину массива, это ясно. Когда смотрю примеры кода, частенько вижу использование `for in len(arr) - 1` или `for in len(arr)`. Пожалуйста, объясните, как это работает или зачем это юзать в цикле .

**Все понятно**

Comment: Вы не могли видеть такие коды, они синтаксически некорректны и не будут работать

Comment: Может там было `for i in range(len(arr))`?

Comment: Да , я ошибся for i in range(1, len(arr)) или for i in range(len(arr))//2 вроде таких

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про len(), хотя вас интересует как работает for. А как работает for написано в каждом учебнике.

Answer (score 8):

Допустим, у вас есть список: `lst = [10, 20, 30, 40]`

И вы хотите пройтись по всем его элементам, допустим, для итерации. С помощью функции `len()` измеряется длина списка. `range()` предоставляет последовательность целых чисел, которые можно использовать как индексы для элементов того же списка. Теперь можно пройтись по элементам в цикле:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] += 1
```

Теперь в вашем списке элементы выглядят так: `[11, 21, 31, 41]`.

Погуглите "Python введение в цикл for".

Answer (score 6):

Если нужно произвести количество итераций равное по длине итерируемому объекту, то используется len.

Пример:

```
for i in range(len(_list)):...
# Иногда лучшим варианиом будет for i in enumerate(_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

Допустим вам нужно пройти по списку сколько - то раз и прибавить к каждому числу в списке + 1. Вы не знаете какой длиной этот список. Как раз для этого вам и нужен `len()`. С помощью `len()` вы узнаёте длину массива и таким образом проходите по списку столько раз и делает что вам нужно.

Answer (score 3):

> *Note*: Вообще надо стараться избегать такого кода т.к.
> часто это плохой код стайл и написание в лоб. Обычно можно делать так: (пример)

Вместо:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] += 1 # do smth with lst[i]
```

Так:

```
lst = list(map(lambda i:i + 1, lst))
```

OR

```
lst = [i + 1 for i in lst]
```

---

Вам уже объяснили что это, но повторю:

> Проитерироваться по списку, получая в `i` индекс текущего элемента

---

Иногда полезна функция `enumerate()`:

```
>>> list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```